# ffmpeg HLS add drawtext in one of the TS files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to add a text to an mpegts file previously encoded. When I run the command below, it works fine but the resulting file cannot be added in the HLS VoD as the previous mpegts file.

```
ffmpeg -y -i ./video1_sem_drm.ts -vf "drawtext=fontfile=./font.ttf: text='Test': fontcolor=black: fontsize=15: x=50: y=50" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -profile:v baseline -q:v 0 -q:a 0 ./video1_new.ts
```

The weird thing is even if I just copy the video and audio streams to the new file, I get the same result.

```
ffmpeg -y -i ./video1_sem_drm.ts -c:v copy -c:a copy -q:v 0 -q:a 0 ./video1_new.ts
```

What would be the correct way to keep the same audio and video encoding and add a text in a single mpegts file?

Thank you

Comment: Srart by finding a way to preserve the original timestamps and timebase. I tried the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66684739/4926757), but it's not working, or I don't understand it. Use FFprobe for reading the timestamps.

Comment: Also, make sure that the original `ts` starts with a key frame (use FFprobe for getting the frame type)

Comment: @Rotem after investigating further, it looks like the issue is with the continuity counter in the mpegts header. I'm not able to keep the counter, ffmpeg is rewriting the mpegts header.